# select2 does not work in boot strap modal

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, jquery-select2

I have a form with an `input class="select2"` element in it, which I call via `$(".select2").select2()`. This works as usual.

Now the thing is, when I insert this form inside modal dialog using AJAX call, it won't load the `select2()` function again and JS and CSS related to `select2` are not loaded.

Comment: can you post what code youve tried or a jsfiddle, so this can be diagnosed and helped?

Answer (score 0):

Select2's CSS and Javascript must be included inside the page where you will have the modal. The requests will be made when the page loads.

Select2 needs to be binded to your element after the modal has loaded. For that you could use the  `success` function relative to the `$.ajax` call.

Alternatively, you could use bootstrap's event, `shown.bs.modal`, fired after the modal has been showned ([see the events section](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-usage) of the modal docs). Something like this:

```
$('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
    $(".select2").select2()
}):
```